# Screen orientation in only one child of a ViewSwitcher in Android

Tags: android, orientation, viewswitcher

I've got a `ViewSwitcher` containing a `LinearLayout` in position 0, and an `ImageView` in position 1.

Now I want the `LinearLayout` only to be shown as **Portrait**, and, when the `ImageView` is shown, give the user the chance to rotate the device and see that view in **Landscape** mode.

So, I added `android:configChanges="orientation"` in the Activity in my `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

Then I need to override `onConfigurationChanged (Configuration newConfig)` in my Activity, but I can't find any way to get what I want...

I've tried editing `newConfig.orientation` param directly, before calling `super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig)`, and also creating a new `Configuration` from `newConfig` and using `updateFrom` method, but It doesn't work.

Any idea?

Thank you

Answer (score -1):

include also keyboardhidden

```
          android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
```